# SharedPreference crash after getting boolean data from the key that was string data

Tags: android, caching, crash, sharedpreferences

I used one key as string data in my app `SharedPreference`.

Later, I didn't need to use string and just boolean is enough.

So I changed to `getBoolean()` to get data and change every usage as boolean.

Even that it still crash.

I don't know exactly why. Please explain me.

Thanks.

Please, I solved it by clearing cache.

**Error :** `cannot parse to boolean`

Is there any other ways to solve it? What I m thinking is that if app is in user phone, it shouldn't crash.

Comment: "cannot parse to boolean" - because a non-boolean value is *still* stored on the device.

Comment: Thanks, is there any other ways to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do a fresh install or clear the cache**.

That is, completley uninstall your app and reinstall again. This will solve your problem.

The reason why you are getting an erro in this situation is that, you already have a String data in your SharedPreference and you are trying to get a boolean data from it. Obviously an error.

The only solution would be to reinstall the app.

**UPDATE**

If you dont want to uninstall or clear the cache, then I think you will have to parse the String to boolean.

Try it like

```
 Boolean boolean1 = Boolean.valueOf(your_sp.getString());
```

Now `boolean1` will contain the boolean value.

Please be sure to overwrite the string in your sharedpreference with a value which wont create problems while parsing to boolean

Comment: Lal, I was solved by cache since early and express in my question. What I want to know is, is there any other solutions to fix without uninstall and clear cache. Sorry. :(. I will update my question.

Comment: Oh great..Hope you got it :)

Comment: Thankyou.. @HeinHtetAung

Comment: Thanks you too bro :)